# How to output a large amount of html markup

Tags: 7

I need to output an entire region of a page from within my custom module.

I know I can output markup to be rendered with this code:

```
$page['region'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => t('markup here'),
);
```

This is good for small amount of markup but is there a better way to output a large amount of html from within my module?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't output large amount of markup from your module without using the theme layer (unless your markup is actually editable content or large chunk of static content). So, the best is probably to [define a theme function or templat](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)e for your markup, and use it from your module. This way, any theme can change your markup without affecting your module logic. Even if this is supposed to be a single-project custom module, chances are that someday you, or somebody else, will have to update this site. Properly separating your module logic from its presentation will make things easier in the future.

```
// Rendering code
  $page['region'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'custom_foo',
      '#foo' => t('foo)',
      '#bar' => t('bar'),
      '#count' => 42
  );

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function custom_theme() {
  return array(
    'custom_foo' => array(
       'variables' => array('foo' => NULL, 'bar' => NULL, 'count' => NULL),
     )
  );
}

/**
 * Default theme implementation for custom_foo.
 */
function theme_custom_foo($variables) {
  $output[] = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $variables['count']; $i++) {
    $output[] = array(
      'type' => '#markup',
      'markup' => ($i % 2 == 0) ? $variables['foo'] : $variables['bar'],
    )
  }
  return $output;
}
```

For static content, you can use a template (.tpl.php) instead of a theme function. This allow you to keep it outside a your .module (or .inc) file code. Again, this will be easier to maintain in the future.

Also, most of the time you shouldn't put markup into [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/t/7). `t()` is for translatable strings and most markup are not to be translated. One common, an acceptable, exceptions is (simple) link markup.

Comment: thanks for your thorough answer. I am actually using a hook_menu which returns a custom template with hook_theme. However all of the output is being rendered into the $page['content'] region. I need some other content to output into a different region as well. Can your solution be adapted to suit this need?

Comment: You can use hook_page_build to add elements to a page before rendering. That's what the block module uses to put blocks into regions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? Be sure to escape double quotes: `\"` or better replace them by single quotes if you can.

```
$markup = "very very ...
... 
long markup";

$page['region'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => $markup,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not placing a large amount of content into form code, as this basically removes the ability for your content authors to edit this content, and any content changes will require code deployments (bad).

My suggestion is to use either

- http://drupal.org/project/queryable_variables (which is great for large pieces of content and acts like a replacement for variable_get()
- http://drupal.org/project/templates (which you can create 'templates' for sections of content you would like to store as nodes, not a perfect solution but maybe what you are looking for).